# Creating a greyscale bathymetry map of the world in QGIS

Tags: qgis, contour, bathymetry, world-imagery

I am looking to create a greyscale bathymetry map of the world in QGIS which I can then output as SVG contour lines. Maybe there is somewhere where I can find and download greyscale vector tiles of the world (possibly DEM) which can then be imported into QGIS 3.10.2 or maybe a plugin for QGIS which loads the bathymetry?

Comment: What research have you conducted? How do the sources you came upon not suit your needs? What resolution do you need? What data formats?

Answer (score 1):

I didnt find a greyscale bathymetry however I did find contour lines which I could import into QGIS from here: https://opendem.info/download_bathymetry.html